# Armadillo: efficient RAM sparse batch insertion

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, ram, armadillo

I know that Sparse matrix in armadillo is still in preliminary support.
I'm using armadillo lib in my quantum systems research and I have problem to construct sparse mat in  effective RAM way.

So far I was using my own implementation of sparse matrixes, but I want to have an optimized matrix class.

I'm filling elements in batch mode:

```
umat loc(2,size);
cx_vec val(size);

// calculate loc and val
...
//

sp_cx_mat Hamiltonian(loc, val);
```

This kind of action copy values from loc,val to constructor of Hamiltonian and for some few seconds require 2x RAM. I calculate huge matrix (size is about 2**L, where L=22, 24, ...) so I wish I had well optimised code in memory.
For comparison, matrix size: 705432x705432 - RAM and "filling time":

- my implementation (COO format): time `7.95s`, memory  `317668kB`
- armadillo (CSC format):  time `5.32s`, memory `715000kB`

Is it possible to deallocate fragments of vectors: `loc`, `val` on the fly to save memory, element by element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here will be to use the other sparse matrix constructor that takes the CSC format, so you will need to modify your `// calculate loc and val` code, instead filling the following three arrays:

- `values` (length equal to number of points)
- `row_indices` (length equal to number of points)
- `col_ptrs` (length equal to number of columns plus one)

The points should be arranged in column-major ordering in the `values` and `row_indices` vectors, and the `col_ptrs` vector contains the number of nonzero elements before the beginning of the column.  That is, `col_ptrs[0]` will always contain 0, `col_ptrs[1]` will contain the number of nonzero elements in the first column, `col_ptrs[2]` will contain the number of nonzero elements in the first and second columns, and `col_ptrs[n_cols + 1]` will contain the number of nonzero elements in the matrix.

For more documentation on this constructor, see the "Batch constructors" section of http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat ; this is the fourth entry in that list.

If you cannot easily modify your calculation code to adhere to that format, then you might be better off trying to specify `sort_locations = false` to the constructor you are using, if you are not already doing that.

Comment: So if I my understanding is correct, constructor using COO format has RAM "consumption" to convert to CSC format, so if I  use constructor with CSC format I'll save RAM, because I won't be doing such conversion?